# Defaulting to 404 when file doesn't exist in nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

Here is my nginx setup:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/web-app/public;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    default_type "text/html";
}

location /profile_images {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

The question is on that second block.  It is a directory full of images.  When I look up an image based on a user id, I may or may not have the image.  If not, I want a 404 error.  Based on the above I am getting a 404 on all images now.  I have tried both `404` and `=404`.

The first location is my api which works fine.

I look up the images (in html) with `src='/profiles_images/***.png'`

For what it is worth, I am using reactjs.

Comment: Where are the image files located? The first `location` includes a `root` directive. If both `location` blocks have a common root, it is usual to define `root` once within the enclosing block.

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't understand what you mean.  Yes, they are both off of the same webroot, but the images are kept in a folder off of the webroot.

Comment: You are missing a `root` statement for `location /profile_images`.

Comment: @RichardSmith  Yup, got it.  I realized that as you said that and that seems to fix it.  Go ahead and add that as an answer if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `root` directive for the second `location` block. Where several `location` blocks share the same value for `root`, it is usual practice to place the `root` statement in the enclosing `server` block so that all `location` blocks inherit the same value. For example:

```
server {
    ...

    index index.html index.htm;
    root /var/www/web-app/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /profile_images {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.